# How bad it is to keep calling malloc() and free()?

Tags: c, network-programming, malloc, free, packets

I'm sending a text file - client-server 
breakup the text into packets each of 512 bytes 
but some packets contain text less than max size so on the servers side when receiving each packet I'm calling malloc() to build a string again , is this a bad practice ?
is it better to keep a working buffer that can fit for max length and keep iterating , copying and overwriting its values ?

okay @n.m. here is the code , this if is inside a for(;;) loop wakened by the select()

```
if(nbytes==2) {
            packet_size=unpack_short(short_buf);
            printf("packet size is %d\n",packet_size);
            receive_packet(i,packet_size,&buffer);
            printf("packet=%s\n",buffer);
            free(buffer);
}
//and here is receive_packet() function 
int receive_packet(int fd,int p_len,char **string) {
 *string = (char *)malloc(p_len-2); // 2 bytes for saving the length    
 char *i=*string;   
 int temp;
 int total=0;
 int remaining=p_len-2;
 while(remaining>0) {
     //printf("remaining=%d\n",remaining);
     temp = recv(fd,*string,remaining,0);
     total+=temp;
     remaining=(p_len-2)-total;
     (*string) += temp;
 }
 *string=i;
 return 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

In your example, your function already contains a syscall, so the relative cost of `malloc`/`free` will be virtually unmeasurable. On my system, a `malloc`/`free` "round trip" averages about 300 cycles, and the *cheapest* syscalls (getting the current time, pid, etc.) cost at least 2500 cycles. Expect `recv` to easily cost 10 times that much, in which case the cost of allocating/freeing memory will be at most about 1% of the total cost of this operation.

Of course exact timings will vary, but the rough orders of magnitude should be fairly invariant across systems. I would not even begin to consider removing `malloc`/`free` as an optimization except in functions that are purely user-space. Where it's probably actually more valuable to go without dynamic allocation is in operations that should not have failure cases - here the value is that you *simplify* and *harden* you code by not having to worry about what to do when `malloc` fails.

Comment: I find it difficult to believe that your malloc/free takes only 300 cycles. Are you using a fragmented heap and including mallocs that need to bring in new memory from the OS and frees that release it?

Comment: I'm timing `free(malloc(1));` (on Linux/glibc/i686, measuring with `rdtsc`) when it does not need to map new memory from the OS, just reusing existing previously-freed memory. This will almost always be the common case. The only time you should worry about time to get new memory from the OS is in realtime programming where you care about the **worst-case** latency of any operation rather than the overall runtime of your program.

Comment: It would be a better test to use an array of 10-100 allocations initialized to NULL and malloc/free random allocation slots of random sizes.

Comment: Feel free to time that yourself and post the results as a comment or an answer.. :-)

Comment: Okay. Interesting stuff. Here's what I found for 16 random slots allocating up to 16384 bytes: tsc average loop = 247
tsc of longest loop = 833292

Comment: And for 512 slots of up to 163840 bytes each: tsc average loop = 408
tsc of longest loop = 294350

Comment: I believe that malloc operation's cost is up to the operation system timing, which literately has to allocate memory for the structure, it's a well known issue in OS course. therefor the time may vary between different OS , system overload ect.

Comment: Suppose a program uses an array variable in a function that gets called zillions of times.  Setting aside all the usual local vs. global declaration issues, is it easier *on the hardware* to malloc and free the array zillions of times (every time the function gets called), than to malloc and free it globally just once?

Comment: @mathematrucker: What does "easier on the hardware" even mean? The two choices you presented are not representative of the actually-resonable ones, which would be either malloc/free each time, or having *the caller* provide an already-allocated workspace (not global).

Answer (score 7):

There is overhead associated with calling malloc and free. A block has to be allocated from the heap and marked as in use, when you free the revese happens. Not knowing what OS or complier you are using, this could be in the c library or at the OS memory managment level. Since you are doing a lot of mallocs and frees you could wind up severly fragmenting your heap where you may not have enough contiguous free memory to do a malloc elsewhere. If you can allocate just one buffer and keep reusing it, that is generally going to be faster and have less danger of heap fragmentation.

Comment: If he is allocating and freeing a fixed-size block over and over, he is almost certainly not fragmenting anything.  (That does not mean there is no overhead...  But fragmentation is probably not what causes it in this case.)

Comment: Assuming that nothing else is allocating memory from the heap in the program, and it is single threaded, I agree. Its probably the same block of memory being returned each time. However, we have no idea what else in the program is allocating from the heap, or how this particular heap manager is implemented.

Comment: With the original purpose of screensavers in mind, if we're talking about a long-running program here then it seems like it might be easier *on the hardware* to malloc and free an array inside a function that gets called zillions of times than to malloc and free it globally just once.  Frankly I have no idea if this is a valid consideration or not...I know that hardware-malicious code exists, but I suspect that global mallocs don't fall into that category :)

Answer (score 4):

I have found that malloc, realloc and free are pretty expensive. If you can avoid malloc it is better to reuse the memory that you've already got.

Edit:
It looks like I am wrong about how expensive malloc is. Some timing tests with the GNU C Library version 2.14 on Linux show that for a test that loops 100,000 times and allocates and frees 512 slots with random sizes from 1 to 163840 bytes:

```
tsc average loop = 408
tsc of longest loop = 294350
```

So wasting 408 cycles doing `malloc` or `new` in a tight inner loop would be a silly thing to do. Other than that don't bother worrying about it.

Answer (score 4):

Malloc is generally fairly inexpensive.  It is only expensive if it generates a syscall to get more heap space.  For instance, in UNIX-Like systems it will eventually generate an sbrk call which will be expensive.  If you repeatedly malloc and free the same size of memory, it will do it crazy fast.  For instance, consider the following little test program:

```
#include <stdlib.h>


int main()
{
  int i=0;
  int *ptr;

  for(int i=0; i<1e6; i++) {
    ptr = malloc(1024*sizeof(int));
    free(ptr);
  }
}
```

It allocates 1024 integers and frees them and does this one million times.  Running this on my rather modest little chromebook turned linux machine, I get timings that look like this:

```
time ./test

real    0m0.125s
user    0m0.122s
sys     0m0.003s
```

Now, if I comment out the malloc and free part of the loop, I get these timings:

```
time ./test

real    0m0.009s
user    0m0.005s
sys 0m0.005s
```

So you see that malloc and free does have overhead, though I think that being just over ten times the overhead of doing nothing is terribly much overhead.

It is especially fast if it can just keep reusing the same chunk of heap over and over again (as is the case here).  Of course, if I kept repeatedly allocating and growing the program, it would take more time because that would result in a few syscalls.

Of course, your mileage may vary depending on OS, compiler, and stdlib implementation.

Answer (score 2):

Calling multiple malloc/free can actually increase the memory used by your process (without any leaks involved), if the size passed to malloc is variable, as proven by this question:

[C program memory usage - more memory reported than allocated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7177274/c-program-memory-usage-more-memory-reported-than-allocated)

So the single buffer approach is probably best.

Answer (score 1):

Only testing can tell. When programming in C I do err on the side of avoiding malloc though, since memory leaks can be quite hard to fix if you create one by accident.

Answer (score 1):

Measure the performance of the two solutions. Either by profiling or measuring throughput. It's impossible to say anything for certain.